# Como acessar tabela de chave estrangeira no Laravel para retornar em uma View

Tags: laravel

Eu estou trabalhando em projeto no laravel e não consigo resolver o seguinte problema:
Tenho uma lista de Atendimento que esta sendo mostrada assim:
[image: Amostra de como esta a lista de atendimento]

Eu queria colocar o nome no lugar do código nas colunas. Porém o nome esta em outra tabela, não sei como acessar.
[image: Código da tabela]

Eu já recebi as Models da chave estrangeira no meu controller, como vocês podem ver ja tenho acesso ao código, mas não sei como fazer o nome do lugar deles, alguma idéia?

Comment: Estás usando relacionamento nessas tabelas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La no seu model atendimento voce precisa definir o relacionamento por exemplo

```
public function pessoa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Model\Pessoa', 'foreign_key_id');
}
```

ai la na sua view dentro do foreach voce consegue acessar assim:

```
@foreach($atendimentos as $atendimentoC)
{{ $atencimentoC->pessoa->nome }}
@endforeach
```

veja a documentação do laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Obrigado faltava justamente a relação!

Answer (score 0):

Eu não consigo visualizar, como você está realizando a query para buscar esses elemtentos, provavelmente se você fizer um inner join entre essas tabelas dê para resgatar. Exemplo:

```
select * from atendimento 
inner join "aqui vai o nome da tabela" on atendimento.atendimento_id = "nome da tabela"."nome da coluna";
```

Depois tente resgatar os valores no foreach.